# Using python scrapy to extract link and text

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I am new to Python and Scrapy. I would like to extract information from website http://www.vodafone.com.au/about/legal/critical-information-summary/plans including the link to document, the name and the valid to.

I tried this code, but it does not work. Would be appreciated if somebody could explain and help me.

Here is the file vodafone.py

```
import scrapy

from scrapy.linkextractor import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import Rule, CrawlSpider
from vodafone_scraper.items import VodafoneScraperItem


class VodafoneSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'vodafone'
    allowed_domains = ['vodafone.com.au']
    start_urls = ['http://www.vodafone.com.au/about/legal/critical-information-summary/plans']

    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//tbody/tr/td[1]/a'):
            item = VodafoneScraperItem()
            item['link'] = sel.xpath('href').extract()
            item['name'] = sel.xpath('text()').extract_first()

            yield item
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because the page content is generated dynamically by JavaScript. Elements which your try to extract data from are not present in HTML source that Scrapy receives as response (you can see yourself when you open page source code in browser).

You have two options:

1. Try to look if you won't find any API that the page uses. Look in browser's developer tools for XHR requests on network tab. Luckily, this concrete page seems to get data from requests like http://www.vodafone.com.au/rest/CIS?field:planCategory:equals=Mobile%20Plans&field:planFromDate:lessthaneq=20/08/2017. It returns JSON which you can parse.
2. The other option is to render the page including JavaScript and parse it then. I recommend using [Splash](https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash) for it's seamless integration with Scrapy via [scrapy-splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash) library.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of request to:

```
    start_urls = ['http://www.vodafone.com.au/about/legal/critical-information-summary/plans']
```

you can set start_urls to:

```
    start_urls = ['http://www.vodafone.com.au/rest/CIS?field:planCategory:equals=Mobile%20Plans&field:planFromDate:lessthaneq=22/08/2017']
```

than convert the response.body to json format:

```
response_json = json.loads(response.body)
```

Now it will give you all the objects on the website. now simply iterate a loop over it and get the required data:

```
for item_json in response_json:
    item["link"] = item_json["document"]["file"]
    item["name"] = item_json["document"]["name"]
```

Complete Code snippet is here:

```
import scrapy
import json
from vodafone_scraper.items import VodafoneScraperItem


class VodafoneSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'vodafone'
    allowed_domains = ['vodafone.com.au']
    start_urls = [
        'http://www.vodafone.com.au/rest/CIS?field:planCategory:equals=Mobile%20Plans&field:planFromDate:lessthaneq=22/08/2017']

def parse(self, response):
    response_json = json.loads(response.body)
    for item_json in response_json:
        item = VodafoneScraperItem()
        item["link"] = item_json["document"]["file"]
        item["book"] = item_json["document"]["name"]

        yield item
```